# Getting Changed/Updated mail list after specific date time

Tags: jakarta-mail

I'm trying to implement a simple sync engine which will sync changes between imap server and my local client, which is developed by javamail API. Is there any method to get newly arrived, flag changed, deleted etc changes in one query from the server against last updated date time value?

Ex: let's say my last sync time is 01/03/2013 @ 23.00.

If I query changes after above time, I'm expecting something like below:

- message id: xxxxxxxxx :- Starred
- message id: yyyyyyyyy :- Deleted
- message id: ppppppppp :- Unread
- message id: ppppppppp :- Starred
- .......
- .......

Or else If you have a better approach to sync between server - client folders please mention  those too. 
Waiting for very quick response.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is no, you can't do that with one query.

The slightly longer answer is that you don't want to do this based on date/time, but rather based on message UID.  That will allow you to detect added/deleted messages.  To detect changes in flags of messages, you'll need to query for all the flags for all the messages and then compare them with saved copies of the flags.

This is the general problem of offline operation and synchronizing offline operations with changes made on the server.  Start with [RFC 4549](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4549.txt) and work backwards to figure out how to do the operations using JavaMail.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip shannon. Now I have the confirmed way to proceed with.